# Replace character in word, but ignoring capitalisation?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to replace a character in a word with a foreign accent character, and apply this to my entire Wordpress site, by adding an action to affect `the_content`, `the_title` and `post_meta`.

However, when using the below, although it works, it will swap the title case of the first letter if the word found begins with a capital, which I want to preserve.

Is there a way to just have one function to replace the character whilst preserving the other letters?

Or would it just be easier to have two functions, one for lowercase, and one for uppercase?

```
function bv_replace_tunbridge($content) {
    $content = str_replace('tunbridge', 't&ucirc;nbridge', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','bv_replace_tunbridge');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to check if the `u` character is an uppercase or lowercase.

```
function bv_replace_tunbridge($content) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/t(u)nbridge/i', function ($match) {
        return str_replace(
            $match[1],
            $match[1] == 'u' ? '&ucirc;' : '&Ucirc;',
            $match[0]
        );
    }, $content);
}
add_filter('the_content','bv_replace_tunbridge');
```

### Output

```
tunbridge // tûnbridge
TUNBRIDGE // TÛNBRIDGE
tUnbridge // tÛnbridge
Tunbridge // Tûnbridge
```

Comment: Whilst this is great, and seems to work fine. Do you know at all how I can incorporate this into `get_post_meta` on Wordpress for certain meta keys?

Comment: @Lee You can add a filter https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_(meta_type)_metadata.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using two functions, you could use regex to search for the criteria you are looking for.

This way you can search for both cases without needing to duplicate code.

Read about `preg_replace()` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: I know that, but it doesn't ignore case in every letter in the string, so I don't see exactly what the difference is. So, do I still need to use two separate functions for upper and lower case?

Comment: I have suggested an alternative method! Please let me know if that would work!